# Applying Format to Entire Row Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an Excel File that I want to format. The first row (excluding Headers so row2) should be red and *italicized*.

the [Openpyxl Documentation states](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.3/styles.html):

> If you want to apply styles to entire rows and columns then you must apply the style to each cell yourself

I personally thinks this stinks... Here is my workaround:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles.colors import RED
from openpyxl.styles import Font
# I normally import a lot of stuff... I'll also take suggestions here.

file = 'MY_PATH'
wb = load_workbook(filename=file)
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Output')

for row in sheet.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if '2' in cell.coordinate:
            # using str() on cell.coordinate to use it in sheet['Cell_here']
            sheet[str(cell.coordinate)].font = Font(color='00FF0000', italic=True)

 wb.save(filename=file)
```

The first downside is that if there are more cells such as `A24` my loop will apply the formatting to it. I can fix this with a regular expression. Would that be the correct approach?

**Ultimately- is there a better way to apply a format to the entire row?** Also. Can anyone point me in the right direction to some *good* Openpyxl documentation? I only found out about `sheet.iter_rows()` and `cell.coordinates` on Stack.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There is no need to iterate on all of the rows if you only intend to change the colour for the second row, you can just iterate over a single row as follows:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font

file = 'input.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(filename=file)
ws = wb['Output']
red_font = Font(color='00FF0000', italic=True)

# Enumerate the cells in the second row
for cell in ws["2:2"]:
    cell.font = red_font

wb.save(filename=file)
```

Giving you something like:

[image: excel screen shot]

Accessing multiple cells is described in the openpyxl docs: [Accessing many cells](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells)

The format `"2:2"` enumerates the cells over a single row. If `"2:3"` is used, this will return the cells a row at a time, i.e. row 2 then row 3 and so would need an additional loop.

---

Alternatively, to use a `NamedStyle`:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font, NamedStyle

file = 'input.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(filename=file)
ws = wb['Output']

# Create a NamedStyle (if not already defined)
if 'red_italic' not in wb.named_styles:
    red_italic = NamedStyle(name="red_italic")
    red_italic.font = Font(color='00FF0000', italic=True)
    wb.add_named_style(red_italic)

# Enumerate the cells in the second row
for cell in ws["2:2"]:
    cell.style = 'red_italic'

wb.save(filename=file)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the type of thing that I wish was documented. I didn't know you could index like that. In fact, the documentation snippet I quoted  is very misleading in light of this approach.

Comment: It is in the docs, but a bit buried maybe [Accessing many cells](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells).

Comment: You deserve the upmost of kudos.

Comment: If you have a lot of cells to format then `NamedStyles` is the way to go.

Comment: @CharlieClark I've used `NamedStyle` before, but how would you apply that to my case?

Comment: link broken: [Accessing many cells](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html?highlight=Accessing%20many%20cells#accessing-many-cells)

Comment: why '2:2' means the entire row 2? I looked into the link but have not found why

Comment: I have updated the text to explain that a bit better. It is just how the library is designed.