# How to change the color of the first row in Excel with Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-styles

I have a code where I am writing a xlsx file :

```
...
...
df.to_excel(finalname,index=False,header=False)
```

Example:

[image]

I would like to write the excel file with color, but just in the first row, like the follow image:

[image]

Maybe I can use the **df.style.apply**,

I tryed that:

```
result.style.apply('background-color: gray',row=[1], axis=1)
```

But it isn´t working

`style.apply` is the correct way ?

If not, how can I get the result of the second image?

Comment: I'm confused.. you've tagged as `php` and `pandas`. But `pandas` is used for Python. If you are looking for a Python solution, maybe have a look at [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). You may be able to come to an answer by looking at one of my more popular questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42980241/applying-format-to-entire-row-openpyxl) *obviously a disclaimer that this is my question

Comment: Jes..  Sorry... I made a confusion! now the tags are ok!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can checkout the python package [xlwings](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html)

Here's how I set an excel range's color:

```py
import xlwings as xw
df.to_excel(finalname,index=False,header=False)
wb = xw.Book(finalname)

# color is set with an rgb value 
wb.sheets['yoursheet'].range('A').color = (169,169,169)
```

I've not adjusted the text color before but I'm pretty sure it's possible. 
xlwings is built on top of pywin32

According to the [docs](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#range) you may be able to get away with setting something like this:

```py
wb.sheets['sheet1'].range('A').api.Font.ColorIndex = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw the other answer, but you can also do this with `df.style()`.

You have two problems. Fist, you are using the wrong syntax. Second, you are trying to style the first row of the data and not the header of the document. The easiest way to get what you are describing would be to use a CSS selector.

```
df.style.set_table_styles([{'selector': 'th', 'props': [('background-color', 'gray')]}])\
    .to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

You also did not export it to excel, just rendered it. The `.to_excel` part is telling it to export. See [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Export-to-Excel) for more information.

Comment: to_excel is not showing the colored header in excel